# How to find out generators of the following free group?

Tags: matrices, group-theory

The following is the quotient group of SL($2,\mathbb{Z}$).

Consider $(H/\{-1,1\} \cap H)$

where $H=\begin{bmatrix}2\mathbb{Z}+1&4\mathbb{Z}\\2\mathbb{Z}&2\mathbb{Z}+1\end{bmatrix}$

How do i find out its generators? I know it is a free group of rank 3 with generators
 \begin{bmatrix}1&4\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\2&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-3&-8\\2&5\end{bmatrix}.

But i have no idea of two things.

$1)$ How to get this generating set and

$2)$ How to prove it is free over these 3 generators?

Comment: Is it really a $4$ in the upper right position?

Comment: @Andreas yes it is 4

Comment: Then how can you have $2$s in the upper right corner of the matrices?

Comment: i have correct some entries

Comment: It cannot be a free group because it contains $-I_2$, so it has a nontrivial centre. I think the three matrices generate a free subgroup of index $2$.

Comment: @ derek how to prove your statment?